# How to make Sign Up and Login ID in Java

Tags: java

I want to ask about my programming code. There seems to be a mistake.  Please check my code below, it didn't turn out to what I had expected. The problem is, I'm imputing the right username but it repeats again. I'd really appreciate all your answers

```
static Scanner scan;
static ArrayList<String> EmailList;
static ArrayList<String> FullNameList;
static ArrayList<String> UsernameList;
static ArrayList<String> PasswordList;

public static void clear(){
    for(int i =0; i < 24; i++){
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static boolean ouragreement (String agreement){
    if(agreement.isEmpty()){
        return false;
        }
    else if(agreement.equalsIgnoreCase("N") || agreement.equalsIgnoreCase ("No")){

        return false;

        }
    return true;

    }

public static boolean validateusername (String username, ArrayList<String>UsernameList){
    if(username.isEmpty()){

        System.out.println("Username cannot be empty");
        return false;

        }

    else if(!username.equals(UsernameList.size())){

        System.out.println("Please input again your username");
        return false;

        }
    return true;

    }//validateusername


public static boolean validatepassword(String password, ArrayList<String>PasswordList){

    if(password.isEmpty()){

        System.out.println("Password cannot be empty");
        return false;
        }
    else if(!password.equals(PasswordList.size())){

        System.out.println("Please input again your password");
        return false;

        }

    return true;



    }//validatepassword




public static void case1(){

    String email, fullname, username, password, agreement;

    System.out.print("Input your email : ");
    email = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Input your Full name : ");
    fullname = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Input your username : ");
    username = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Input your password : ");
    password = scan.nextLine();

    EmailList.add(email);
    FullNameList.add(fullname);
    UsernameList.add(username);
    PasswordList.add(password);


    do{
        System.out.print("If you say Yes[Y], you agreed to our Terms & Privacy Policy [Y/N] : ");
        agreement = scan.nextLine();
    }while(!ouragreement(agreement));


    clear();
        System.out.println("Sign Up Success!");

        System.out.println();



    }//case1




public static void case2(){

    String username,password;

    do{
        System.out.print("Username : ");
        username = scan.nextLine();
    }while(!validateusername(username,UsernameList));

    do{
        System.out.print("Password : ");
        password = scan.nextLine();
    }while(!validatepassword(password,PasswordList));


    System.out.println("Welcome");







    }//case2



public static void inisialisasi (){

    scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    EmailList = new ArrayList<>();
    FullNameList = new ArrayList <>();
    UsernameList = new ArrayList<>();
    PasswordList = new ArrayList<>();


    }//inisialisasi




public static void main (String [] args){

    inisialisasi();

    int choose;

    do{
    System.out.println("\tKOSTFINDER APPLICATION");
    System.out.println("\t======================\n");


    System.out.println("Welcome to KostFinder Application, please choose option below");

    System.out.println("1. Sign up");
    System.out.println("2. Login");
    System.out.print("Choose :");
    choose = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
    switch(choose){
        case 1 :
        case1();
        break;

        case 2 :
        case2();
        break;


        }
}while(choose != 101);






    }//main






}//public class
```

Comment: the condition if(!username.equals(UsernameList.size())) will be always true because you're comparing a string with an int

Comment: maybe you want to check if the list contains your username

Comment: In the future please show the errors thrown. Please refer to: [Ask]. You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before posting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr Buda, Sorry but i'm comparing the data type String with .equals, if int, i think int should be compare with == or !=. so i think there's no problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i will keep in my mind @T-Heron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in these two methods:

```
public static boolean validateusername (String username, ArrayList<String>UsernameList){
    if(username.isEmpty()){

        System.out.println("Username cannot be empty");
        return false;

        }

    else if(!username.equals(UsernameList.size())){

        System.out.println("Please input again your username");
        return false;

        }
    return true;

}//validateusername


public static boolean validatepassword(String password, ArrayList<String>PasswordList){

    if(password.isEmpty()){

        System.out.println("Password cannot be empty");
        return false;
        }
    else if(!password.equals(PasswordList.size())){

        System.out.println("Please input again your password");
        return false;

        }

    return true;



}//validatepassword
```

The condition `!password.equals(PasswordList.size())` does not make much sense. You should find the index of the entered user name in the user names list, find the password at that index in the passwords list and check whether the entered password is equal to that password. This means that you should really create a single method that validates both password and user name. This is because passwords and user names are highly related. You can't know whether a password is correct without knowing the user name.

Also, you did not check whether the new user name added to the list is duplicate or not. Not to mention that you allowed empty user names and passwords to be entered in the sign up process while not allowing them when logging in. But these are smaller problems relative to the problem mentioned in the previous paragraph.

Your `validateUsernameAndPassword` method should look like this:

```
public static boolean validateUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password) {
    int index = UsernameList.indexOf(username);
    if (index == -1) { 
        System.out.println("The user name does not exist");
        return false; 
    }
    String correctPassword = PasswordList.get(index);
    if (correctPassword.equals(password)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please input again your password");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: This way of storing passwords is **highly** insecure. I understand this is not production code, but never do something like this in production code. At least you should do a hashing algorithm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr Sweeper, when i put your code inside my textpad 7, there's an error, and the massage is

error: incompatible types
    String correctPassword = PasswordList.indexOf(index);
                                                 ^
  required: String
  found:    int
1 error

how can i fix it? Thank You

Comment: @Hendra Oh oops! My bad! That was a typo. Replace that line with `String correctPassword = PasswordList.get(index);`

Comment: Thank You very much Mr Sweeper, your answer really helped me :)

Comment: @Hendra If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark!